# Problems with Netflix in new Google Chrome

Tags: release-freya, google-chrome, graphics

I've been watching Netflix in Google Chrome for months without any problem. Since one of the last updates however, there are weird graphical glitches. If you start a stream, you can only hear the audio. Otherwise the screen remains black or will just show the preview pic, and if you start hovering above the timeline with the mouse, the little thumbnails that pop up will stay. Also, if you scroll down in the menu you get the same effect. It looks like this:

[image]

[image]

I'm using **Google Chrome 50.0.2661.94** (64-bit) on freya 0.3.2. So far as I know it is the current version. I have an **i7-6500U CPU** and an **AMD Radeon R5 M335** graphics card. I've tried other videos, they work fine.

Any ideas??!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling hardware acceleration in the Chrome settings fixed the problem. Don't ask me why though ;)

Comment: The video will be slow and will take lots of battery and CPU power = heat and loud

Comment: maybe, but that's certainly better than the video not working at all

Comment: oh, and it's not slow at all btw